# Overriding legend symbol size in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to override my symbol size aes using commands I have found in this forum and elsewhere. I can get the alpha override to work but not the size.

```
f1<-ggplot(data=d, aes(x=rpos, y=count, group=id,color=id)) +
geom_point(alpha=0.05, size=0.5) +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "red")) + 
scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue", "red")) +
xlab("Chromosome 1") +
scale_y_continuous(name="Relative coverage",limits=c(-0.5,1.5)) +
guides(colour =guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=5))) +
guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1))) +
theme_bw()

optns <- theme (
      plot.title = element_text(face="bold", size=14),
      axis.title.x = element_text(size=12),
      axis.title.y = element_text(size=12, angle=90),
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      legend.position = c(.97,.85),
      legend.text = element_text(size=10),
      legend.key.size = unit(1, "lines"),
      legend.key = element_blank(),
      legend.justification = 'right'
 ) 

f1 + ggtitle ("Coverage of Chromosome 1") + 
optns + ggsave("Rel.mergedDataChr1.pdf", width = 20, height = 5, dpi = 100)
```

Comment: It's hard to replicate/solve your issue without knowing what your data looks like. Please provide a `dput()` of (part of) your data. I think you need to override the aesthethics in one line (as you overwrite the colour with the alpha), so maybe something like `+guides(colour=guideL-egend(override.aes=list(size=5,alpha=1)))` works?

Answer (score 8):

Your alpha override is overwriting your size override. Change this:

```
guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=5))) +
guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1))) +
```

to this:

```
guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=5, alpha = 1))) +
```

In the future, please try to include *minimal working* examples. This means both providing data (to make it a working example) and also not bothering with things like all your `optns` (to keep it minimal).